# Unique Dictionaries in a list of dictionaries(c#)

Tags: c#, list, generics, dictionary

I want to create a generic class which helps me to compare two dictionary (both keys and values)

```
class DictionaryComparer : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> //doesn't work. But i want to make it generic

class DictionaryComparer : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string,string>> //works. Not generic
```

I would use the reference of IEqualityComparer using `Distinct(IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string,string>> comparer)` on a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` . So that i have only unique dictionaries in a list.

Is there any better way have unique dictionaies in a list

Comment: Have you tried `class DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>>`

Comment: This works. Is there a better way to compare two dictionaries in a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue> 
    : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>>
```

Might work.

Comment: This works. Is there a better way to compare two dictionaries in a list of dictionaries .

Comment: @user1650470 I was thinking about it. I'm not sure, but I guess you'd have to implement a dictionary which created a hashcode while adding items. Then you could compare the hashes. This is the best I could think by now.